# reading multi valued columns from access into c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, oledb, ms-jet-ace

I would like to use multivalued in access to make it easier for the user.

But when reading it into c# using `oledb` I get the first value followed by garbage
using `columnname.value` gets me multiple rows of the exact same data and only that column is different which seems like a waste to me.

Is there a better way?

I know multi values are not supported in sql nor Oracle but it would make it much easier for the user so I would like to keep it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

Yes: ODBC.

When it comes to handling multi-valued fields (created by the "Lookup Wizard" in Access), `Odbc` seems to do a better job than `OleDb` does. For test data in a table named [multiValueTest]

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| ID | Description | Attributes |
+----+-------------+------------+
|    |             | attribute1 |
|  1 | foo         | attribute2 |
|    |             | attribute4 |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

the query

```sql
SELECT Attributes FROM multiValueTest WHERE ID=1
```

does indeed return garbage characters when retrieved by an `OleDbDataReader` object.

However, that same query retrieved by an `OdbcDataReader` object, specifically

```csharp
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString =
            @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
            @"Dbq=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";
    con.Open();
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Attributes FROM multiValueTest WHERE ID=1";
        OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
        rdr.Close();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

returns a single string value like this

```
attribute1;attribute2;attribute4
```

which can then be split on the semi-colon (`;`) character and handled appropriately.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Gord.
Too late though, the whole access idea was scrapped. :(

Comment: @AngelicCore Oh well, at least this question might help the next person. Thanks for accepting the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time but did you solve this problem? MultiValue databases can but do not need to store data in multi-valued attributes.

One option would be to normalize the data in the DBMS with BASIC prior to export, writing to a new work file in a flat format which can be understood by relational tools (ADO.NET, etc).

Depending on the tools you use to extract the data from the DBMS you might already have the ability to normalize multi-valued records into a dataset. Examples of such tools include UniObjects or U2.NET Toolkit for Universe and Unidata, MVSP for D3 and mvBase, QMClient for QM, and MVSP for all MV platforms.

If you must export multivalues, you can do a simple Split on the value marks (xFD) and convert them into a string[] or List.

As you said, RDBMS/SQL tools don't support multiple values. So to moving that data into a relational/normalized format you will either need to create multiple records with some data duplication, or create another table and join to it with a foreign key. This is one technique the various products use to make MV look relational. For example, you'll have a Customer record which points to a CustomerPhones table which has one record for each phone for that customer ... when they were originally just multivalues within your single Customer record.

Comment: Sadly no, I scrubbed this idea because it led to nowhere.

Comment: If you do take on MVs again, let me know. Depending on your platform, location, and other factors, there are a ton of resources available for doing this sort of thing. You're not alone, but this query was posted to a site here that isn't frequented by MV people. That's starting to change now.

Answer (score 0):

Use msdatashape provider.  This provides a ; delimited list.  Sample Connection String: Provider=MsDataShape;Data Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12;Data Source=(Your Path)